# questions on using .grad within torch.no_grad()

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient, backpropagation

I wrote some toy examples to understand how torch.no_grad() works:

```
# example 1
import torch
a = torch.randn(10, 5, requires_grad = True)
z = a * 3
l = z - 0.5
l.sum().backward()
with torch.no_grad():
  a -= a.grad
  print(a.requires_grad)
# True
```

So, `a -= a.grad` inside `with torch.no_grad()` will keep the a.requires_grad = True

```
# example2
import torch
a = torch.randn(10, 5, requires_grad = True)
z = a * 3
l = z - 0.5
l.sum().backward()
with torch.no_grad():
  a = a - a.grad
  print(a.requires_grad)
# False
```

But, `a -= 1` inside `with torch.no_grad()` will set a.requires_grad = False

```
# example3
import torch
a = torch.randn(10, 5, requires_grad = True)
z = a * 3
l = z - 0.5
l.sum().backward()
a -= a.grad
print(a.requires_grad)
# RuntimeError: a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation.
```

`a -= a.grad` without `with torch.no_grad()` will throw RuntimeError (but `a -= 1` does not)

I could not find explanations for the above results. Could somebody point a direction ?
Many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I thought the anwser above did not explain the 3 cases explicitly.

### case 1

`a -= a.grad` is a in place operation so it will not change the attribute `require_grad` of a. Thus `a.require = True`

### case 2

`a = a - a.grad` is not a in place operation so it create a new tensor object in memory space. Since in no grad mode, `a.require = False`

### case 3

you can not change a leaf tensor with `require grad = True` outside `no grad` mode.

See [discuss](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/leaf-variable-was-used-in-an-inplace-operation/308/2)

I also try the code below

```py
import torch
a = torch.tensor([1.1], requires_grad=True)
b = a ** 2
b.backward()
a -= 1
```

it do throw the same runtime error!

I hope my answer will help you

Answer (score 0):

This `a.grad` is None and becomes a Tensor the first time a call to `backward()` is made.

The `grad` attribute will then contain the gradients computed and future calls to `backward()` will accumulate (add) gradients into it.

If you use `with torch.no_grad():` then PyTorch autograd engine is disabled so you don't have the error.

`requires_grad = True` is an indicator to record gradients on a tensor.

The error you are getting in the last example is telling you you cannot use the `a.grad` for in-place operations but you may use `a=a-a.grad` just for the example:

```
# example3
import torch
a = torch.randn(10, 5, requires_grad = True)
z = a * 3
l = z - 0.5
l.sum().backward()
a = a -a.grad
print(a.grad)
print(a.requires_grad)
```

Out:

```
None
True

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/_tensor.py:1013: UserWarning: The .grad attribute of a Tensor that is not a leaf Tensor is being accessed. Its .grad attribute won't be populated during autograd.backward(). If you indeed want the .grad field to be populated for a non-leaf Tensor, use .retain_grad() on the non-leaf Tensor. If you access the non-leaf Tensor by mistake, make sure you access the leaf Tensor instead. See github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/30531 for more informations. (Triggered internally at  aten/src/ATen/core/TensorBody.h:417.)
  return self._grad
```

Comment: Many thanks. I think I got the idea on the last Runtime-error. Still I don't know why the in-place operation keeps a.require_grad=True, while normal assignment operation set a.require_grad=False

Comment: You may notice the I rewrote your 3-rd example a bit, and `a.require_grad` is `True`. So my rewrite is not in place. PS> this code is just for the purpose of an example.